# Arduino: cannot get value from array of struct

Tags: arrays, struct, serial-port, arduino

I have a bidimensional array of struct that I defined and I want to get a value in a struct which itself is contained in an array.

I have tried to do the same kind of code in bare C and it seems to work while or Arudino IDE it doesn't (code isn't the exact same but it's generally the same thing).

Look at the example below, I am printing an arbitrary value taken out of my array of struct over serial and the only input I get on the Serial Monitor is a suit of 'ÿ' which from what I've seen on the internet means that the serial buffer is empty.

Does anything look wrong to you within the code below? **(look at the end to see the relevant code)**

```
#include <Wire.h>

typedef struct {
  char nom[17]; // wanted number +1 for terminaison
  byte cor1[2]; // correspondance
  byte cor2[2];
  byte cor3[2];
  byte cor4[2];
  byte i2c;
  byte led;
} Station;

Station lignes[14][15] = {{
  {"Champs Elysees", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11101111},
  {"Concorde", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B10111111},
  {"Tuileries", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B11101111},
  {"Palais Royal", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B10111111},
  {"Louvre Rivoli", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B11101111},
  {"Chatelet", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B10111111},
  {"Hotel de Ville", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B11101111},
  {"St-Paul", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11011111},
  {"Bastille", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11110111},
  {"Ledru-Rollin", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11110111},
  {"Faidherbe", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111011}
},
{
},
{
  {"Saint-Lazare", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11111110},
  {"Havre Caumartin", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B11111110},
  {"Opera", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B11110111},
  {"Quatre Septembre", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B11111101},
  {"Bourse", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B11011111},
  {"Sentier", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B11110111},
  {"R. Sebastopol", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B11111101},
  {"Arts et Metiers", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B01111111},
  {"Temple", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B10111111},
  {"Republique", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11110111}
},
{
  {"S. Saint-Denis", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11011111},
  {"R. Sebastopol", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B11111101},
  {"Etienne Marcel", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B11111011},
  {"Les Halles", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B10111111},
  {"Chatelet", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B10111111},
  {"Cite", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B01111111},
  {"St-Michel", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111110},
  {"Odeon", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111101},
  {"St-Germain", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100101, B10111111},
  {"Saint-Sulpice", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B10111111},
  {"St-Placide", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B01111111},
  {"Montparnasse", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111},
  {"Vavin", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B01111111},
  {"Raspail", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111011},
  {"Denfert", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111}
},
{
  {"J. Bonsergent", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11111011},
  {"Republique", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11110111},
  {"Oberkampf", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B01111111},
  {"Richard Lenoir", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111110},
  {"Breguet Sabin", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111101},
  {"Bastille", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11110111},
  {"Quai de la Rapee", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111101},
  {"Gare Austerlitz", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111},
  {"Saint Marcel", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B10111111},
  {"Campo Formio", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11011111},
},
{
  {"Pasteur", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11011111},
  {"Montparnasse", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111},
  {"Edgar Quinet", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B10111111},
  {"Raspail", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111011},
  {"Denfert", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111}
},
{
  {"Le Peletier", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B11110111},
  {"La Fayette", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B11111011},
  {"Opera", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B11110111},
  {"Pyramides", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B01111111},
  {"Palais Royal", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B10111111},
  {"Pont Neuf", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B11011111},
  {"Chatelet", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B10111111},
  {"Pont Marie", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111101},
  {"Sully Morland", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111110},
  {"Jussieu", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111011},
  {"Place Monge", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11110111},
  {"C. Daubenton", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111011},
  {"Les Gobelins", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B10111111},
},
{
  {"Invalides", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100101, B11110111},
  {"Concorde", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B10111111},
  {"Madeleine", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11011111},
  {"Opera", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B11110111},
  {"Richelieu Drouot", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B11111101},
  {"Gds Boulevards", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B11111011},
  {"Bonne Nouvelle", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B11111110},
  {"S. Saint-Denis", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11011111},
  {"Republique", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11110111},
  {"F. du Calvaire", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11101111},
  {"St-S. Froissart", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B01111111},
  {"Chemin Vert", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B01111111},
  {"Bastille", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11110111},
  {"Ledru Rollin", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11110111},
  {"Faidherbe", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111011}
},
{
  {"Saint Philippe", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11110111},
  {"Miromesnil", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11111011},
  {"Saint-Augustin", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11111101},
  {"Havre Caumartin", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B11111110},
  {"La Fayette", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B11111011},
  {"Richelieu Drouot", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100110, B11111101},
  {"Gds Boulevards", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100010, B11111011},
  {"Bonne Nouvelle", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B11111110},
  {"S. Saint-Denis", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11011111},
  {"Republique", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11110111},
  {"Oberkampf", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B01111111}
},
{
  {"Duroc", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11110111},
  {"Vanneau", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B01111111},
  {"Sevres Babylone", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111011},
  {"Mabillon", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100101, B01111111},
  {"Odeon", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111101},
  {"La Sorbonne", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111101},
  {"Maubert", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11011111},
  {"Cardinal Lemoine", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B01111111},
  {"Jussieu", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111011},
  {"Gare Austerlitz", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111}
},
{
  {"Chatelet", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B10111111},
  {"Hotel de Ville", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B11101111},
  {"Rambuteau", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B11011111},
  {"Arts et Metiers", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B01111111},
  {"Republique", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11110111},
  {"Goncourt", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11111101},
  {"Belleville", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100000, B11111110}
},
{
  {"Saint-Lazare", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11111110},
  {"Madeleine", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11011111},
  {"Concorde", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B10111111},
  {"Assemblee", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100101, B11111011},
  {"Solferino", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100101, B11111110},
  {"Rue du Bac", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100101, B11101111},
  {"Sevres Babylone", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111011},
  {"Rennes", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111},
  {"N-D. Des-Champs", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11011111},
  {"Montparnasse", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111},
  {"Falguiere", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B10111111},
  {"Pasteur", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11011111},
  {"Volontaires", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111}
},
{
  {"Saint-Lazare", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11111110},
  {"Miromesnil", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11111011},
  {"Champs Elysees", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11101111},
  {"Invalides", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100101, B11110111},
  {"Varenne", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100101, B11111101},
  {"St-Fr. Xavier", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100101, B11011111},
  {"Duroc", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11110111},
  {"Montparnasse", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11101111},
  {"Gaite", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11111110}
},
{
  {"Saint-Lazare", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11111110},
  {"Madeleine", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B11011111},
  {"Pyramides", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100001, B01111111},
  {"Chatelet", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0100100, B10111111},
  {"Gare de Lyon", {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, B0111000, B11110111}
}};


void setup() {
//  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
//  for (int j=0; j<16; j++) {
  byte a = lignes[0][0].i2c;
  Serial.write(a);
/*  for (int i=0; i<14; i++) {
    Serial.print(lignes[0][i].i2c, BIN);
    Serial.print(lignes[0][i].led, BIN);
    Serial.println(" ");

/*    Wire.beginTransmission(lignes[0][i].i2c); // PCF8574P GGG
    Wire.write(lignes[0][i].led);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    delay(10);*/
//  }
// }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help, I already spent a lot of time on this...

Comment: What language is this? Serial.write(a); doesn't look like c to me. Anyway, have you validated your serial connection works by just doing a basic Serial.write("Hello world");?

Comment: ÿ is all 8 bits set to 1, 255 or -1 depending on the interpretation/sign.

Comment: If all your names are going to be compile-time constants, you should switch the `char nom[17]` field to a `const char *nom`.

Comment: @BrandonYates It's Arduino, and yeah the Hello World kind of thing works well, it's just that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it was caused by a memory overflow (thanks to Arduino IDE for NOT pointing that).

The Arduino IDE says 36kB available but that's Flash memory, one has to account SRAM.

This is worked-around by using PROGMEM.

cf. http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory
http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM

Also be careful, you have to use special functions for extracting and using value stored with PROGMEM.

Answer (score 2):

In your given example, you are writing "lignes[0][0].i2c" which is B0100001. That is an [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code for space. Try validating your serial conection with a simple

```
Serial.Write("Hello World");
```

If that passes then try printing an actual string, for example,

```
Serial.Write(&lignes[0][0].nom)
```

Comment: Apparently, Arduino doesn't like to point to a struct element contained in an array... maybe compiler problem.